# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi' using Docker-gstreamer

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

I'm using Docker - Gstreamer and I faced an error regarding the packages, I tried multiple ways but still this error showing every time I run the code.

Also, I tried all the possible command given below (I'm using MAC):

```
pip3 install pgi , pip3 install PyGObject , pip3 install python-gi
```

And this is the code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib

def initialize_gstreamer():
    Gst.init(None)

def create_gstreamer_pipeline():
  
    pipeline_str = ("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink")

    return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_str)

def main():
    initialize_gstreamer()
```

And this is the error i faced :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/app/gst_main.py", line 1,
> in 
> import gi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'